# Alterar a borda da div e ao mesmo tempo mostrar o valor em outra tag HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Tenho uma `div` que eu vou alterar o valor `borderRadius` e ela vai arredondar.
E tenho um `input` que é do tipo `range` para controlar o valor do arredondamento.

E ao mesmo tempo vou exibir o valor do `range` na tag `output`.

Não estou conseguindo arredondar o elemento html, como posso fazer isso?

```
<div class="box" style="text-align: center;">
    <!--Div para arredondar-->
</div>

<label for="range">Borda:</label>
<input type="range" id="range" min="0" step="5" max="50" value="0" 
oninput="document.getElementById('rangeValor').value = document.getElementById('range').value;
document.getElementById('box').style.borderRadius = document.getElementById('range').value;"
>
<output id="rangeValor">0</output>%<br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você esqueceu de definir o tipo de medida em `'borderRadius'`. Você pode declarar `'px'` na frente do valor que vai declarar.

(Agora que fui ver a observação do @AndrewRibeiro (não notei muito o HTML), assim editei o código da resposta. `document.getElementsByTagName`, esse método retorna um objeto (semelhante à array), `HTMLCollection`, de elementos HTML que contém uma classe específica.)

```
var range = parseFloat(document.getElementsById('range').value);

var box = document.getElementsByTagName('box')[0],
    output = document.getElementById('rangeValor');

output.value =
box.style.borderRadius = range + 'px';
```

---

*Explicação melhor para esse `0` entre os colchetes*

Basicamente, os colchetes são uma forma de indexar um objeto computadamente. Exemplo:

`box['style']`

é o mesmo que

`box.style`.

O ponto `.` e os colchetes `[...]` te permitem indexar objetos com um valor específico, esse valor retorna uma propriedade do objeto, ou `undefined`. Portanto, o ponto `.` só deixa você indexar um objeto com uma string na frente. Ou seja, `box.style`, aqui nós indexamos `box` com a string `style`.

Olha um exemplo:

```
alert(({ hello: 'blabla' }).hello); // blabla
alert(({ hello: 'blabla' })['hello']); // blabla
alert(({}).hello); // undefined
```

Portanto você não pode indexar valores do tipo `undefined` ou `null`. Você só pode indexar números, etc... pois eles são instância de `Object`.

---

E, para mais informação, o que `document.getElementsByTagName` retorna não é *exatamente* uma array, é um objeto comúm, porém ele pode não incluir os métodos que `Array` tem em JavaScript (tipo `forEach`, `push`, etc...), mas você pode conveter ele para uma `Array` sim. Não estou afirmando que o objeto não vá incluir esses métodos, pois uma de suas instâncias podem incluir um método parecido em `prototype`.

Comment: Pq do 0 entre o colchete ?
Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Victor Editei a resposta.

Comment: me desculpa nao responder antes, eu estou meio que começando no Js.
Eu ainda não cheguei mt longe e nao vi array(so vi no php).
Obrigado pela resposta e eu nao tenho escolha a não ser estudar rsrsrsrs.

Comment: SS, entendi agr muito obrigado pela explicação.
add no skype: vitim_fernandes

Comment: @Victor Adicionei, não tenho certeza se achei sua conta certa :v, são várias pessoas do mesmo nome

Answer (score 4):

Além do que @nicematt sugeriu, você está definindo uma `class` para a div e está tentando pegar o elemento utilizando `getElementById`.

Fiz uma modificação no seu código, agora está funcionando.

Espero ter ajudado.

```html
<div id="box" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid">
  <!--Div para arredondar-->
  TESTE
</div>

<label for="range">Borda:</label>
<input type="range" id="range" min="0" step="5" max="50" value="0" oninput="document.getElementById('rangeValor').value = document.getElementById('range').value;
document.getElementById('box').style.borderRadius = document.getElementById('range').value + 'px';">
<output id="rangeValor">0</output>%
<br>
```

Comment: Nossa, eu estou errando coisas simples demais.
Obg pela ajuda!

Comment: Só pude ler sua pergunta agora.... Mas já está bem respondida!